# MDIchild windows, not stacking more than the center of the screen. A known limit?

Tags: c#, winforms, mdi, mdichild

This is simply an annoyance.
But the system seems to stack child windows properly for a while, but then at some point, before you expect it to, it begins re-stacking them over the top of the ones you've already laid.

Are there any configurations I can set?  I mean for the size of the MDI setup that I'm missing.  It seems to stop before the center of the screen.  I will post a picture of a test project, but it is a little similar to what happens in the real project.  I realize that I can do a 'Cascade' and other functions, to windows after they already in place.  But that is not desirable.  I also realize that MDI forms fell out of fashion a while back.  Well... I'm not getting rid of them yet.[image]

Comment: Built-in Windows behavior, there are no knobs to tweak.  If you don't like it then you'll have to take care of positioning the window yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what Hans was saying:
In the test project I put this, and it works... 
Note: This is in the load of the MDIChild.

```
    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int t = 1, l = 1;
        int d = this.MdiParent.MdiChildren.GetUpperBound(0) - 1;
        if (d >= 0)
        {
            Form f = this.MdiParent.MdiChildren[d];
            t = f.Top + 20;
            l = f.Left + 20;
        }

        this.Top = t;
        this.Left = l;
    }
```